# Some properties destroying other properties?

Tags: css

[Codepen page](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGoWyq)

[Webpage hosted with Google Drive](http://googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptWUNxU0swQ1ZQUkE) if you want to see it with pictures (front.html)

relevant code:

```
.row1 img{
    /*box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 7px rgb(0,256,0);/*the line that breaks .border-blue and .border-orange shadows*/
}
.blue-border{
    border: 4px solid rgb(0,102,179);
}
.orange-border{
    border: 4px solid rgb(208,78,29);
}
.title-blue,.blue-border,.title-orange,.orange-border{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgb(117,117,117);
}
```

I'm creating a webpage for my school, and I need to create inset box-shadows on 4 elements: the two images in the 1st row, and the .blue-border and .orange-border divs in the 2nd row. However, there is already a box-shadow property applied to the borders, so applying a new box-shadow property cancels out the original ones. Also, when I apply a box-shadow property to the images in .row1 (ln 25), the box-shadow of the borders breaks. How do I circumvent the fact that CSS can't handle 2 identical properties with different arguments? And why does the box-shadow on the images in .row1 break the box-shadow of the .blue-border and .orange-border classes?

Thank you!